# Test if quicklisp has already been installed in clisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, quicklisp

I'm working on a project in Common Lisp which makes use of a package installed with quickload.  I'm making a bash script in the root of the project which tests if the necessary programs are installed, and if it all checks out, it runs a lisp script which loads my project.  I want some way of testing if quicklisp is installed, so that I can have it can ask the user for permission to download and install quicklisp automatically.  Is there a way to test for this?  Quicklisp is installed within clisp, not as a package on the OS, so using the bash builtins for testing if a program's installed won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From inside Lisp: Quicklisp puts `:quicklisp` onto the `cl:*features*` list.
If Quicklisp is already loaded into Lisp, then this symbol is on the `*features*` list.

To test that:

```
(member :quicklisp *features*)
```

In Lisp code you can also use the conditional reader:

```
#+quicklisp (print "quicklisp installed")
```

or

```
#-quicklisp (print "quicklisp not installed")
```